# C# lambda unnamed parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, lambda

is it possible, to discard some arguments in lambda expressions by don't give them a name?
E.g. I have to pass a Action<int,int>, but I'm only interested in the second param, i want to write something like

```cs
(_, foo) => bar(foo)
// or
(, foo) => bar(foo)
```

In the first case it is working. But the first parameter isn't really unnamed, because it has the name "_". So it isn't working, when I want to discard two or more. I choose _ because in prolog it has the meaning "any value".

So. Is there any special character or expression for my use case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you can't. Looking at the [C# language specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc) grammar, there are two ways to declare lambdas: explicit and implicit. Neither one allows you to skip the identifier of the parameter or to reuse identifiers (names).

```
explicit-anonymous-function-parameter:
  anonymous-function-parameter-modifieropt   type   identifier

implicit-anonymous-function-parameter:
  identifier
```

It's the same as for unused function parameters in ordinary functions. They have to be given a name.

Of course you can use `_` as the name for one of the parameters, as it is a valid C# name, <del>but it doesn't mean anything special.</del>

As of C# 7, `_` *does* have a special meaning. Not for lambda expression parameter names but definitely for other things, such as pattern matching, deconstruction, out variables and even regular assignments. (For example, you can use `_` = 5; without declaring `_`.)

Comment: `_` *does* have a special meaning as of C# 7. Not for lambda expression parameter names (as far as I can tell) but definitely for other things, such as pattern matching, deconstruction, `out` variables and even regular assignments. (For example, you can use `_ = 5;` without declaring `_`.) I realize this answer was written several years before C# 7, but given that the last line has become incorrect, it would be good to edit this if you have time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for noticing, I added your comments in an edit. I need to get better at predicting the future.

Comment: I'm often in the same position - in this case I hadn't actually noticed that it was an old answer for quite a while... the new answer had put the question on the front page.

Comment: So to summarize, the expression `new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(_ => DoStuff(_))` is syntactically correct but semantically wrong? I see this all over the place and just found out about the discard pattern. To me it is seems practical to not having to clutter a tiny lambda with characters #firstworldproblems

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is: no, you have to name every parameter, and the names have to be unique.

You can use `_` as one parameter name because it is a valid identifier in C#.

However, you can only use it once.

Comment: Which is why I so often end up with `(_, __, ___, foo) => { ... }`

Comment: Note that discards for lambda functions is being tracked as a language feature in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/111

Answer (score 5):

## Now You Can!

From C# 9.0 onwards, you can use the underscore character to "discard" one **or more** lambda parameters. From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#input-parameters-of-a-lambda-expression):

> Beginning with C# 9.0, you can use discards to specify two or more input parameters of a lambda expression that aren't used in the expression:

```
Func<int, int, int> constant = (_, _) => 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7, you can use discards. Discards are write only variables which you can not read. It is basically for variables that you do not wish to use
more details [here](http://www.devsanon.com/c/using-discards-feature-of-c-7/)

Comment: This is true and has been missed by other answers, but isn't relevant in the case of lambda expression parameters as far as I can tell. (You can't use `(_, _, x) => x` for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet so you cannot use this?
(_, foo) => bar(foo)

Comment: You can, but then `_` is just a regular parameter. You can't use `(_, _, x)` because then you'd be declaring the same parameter twice. (Whereas you can use `_` multiple times in patterns.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, now I get it